# Sending text to controller through Ajax Method

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a bit of trouble sending my data to my controller through the ajax request I'm using.

Currently in my view, I have

```
 <p>Please enter your email and phone number registered with the account</p>
   <table id="Table">
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td> <input id = "email" type ="text" name= "email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td> <input id = "phone" type ="text" name= "phone" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sendMSG">
```

and the following script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
        </script>

<script>
$("#sendMSG").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SendMessage", "SMSTest")',
        dataType: "JSon",
        data: { "email": $("#email").toString(), "phone": $("#phone").toString()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: console.log("it did not work"),
    });
});
</script>
```

When I call the function, I send it to my `SMSTestController`

```
 public JsonResult SendMessage(string email, string phone)
        {}
```

what I currently get as the email and phone are the values `[object Object]` which is a type string for both my email and phone after clicking the button.

do you have any idea on how to send the actual string I enter in the textbox directly to the controller?

Thanks

Comment: To get input's value, you have to write : $("#email").val();

Comment: @Joffrey Kem thanks a bunch! appreciate it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not grabbing the values of the input fields, but rather you are sending up the entire objects themselves as strings.

Try:

```
data: { "email": $("#email").val(), "phone": $("#phone").val()},
```

Answer (score 3):

your Javascript is wrong you need to use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
<script>
$("#sendMSG").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SendMessage", "SMSTest")',
        dataType: "JSon",
        data: { "email": $("#email").val(), "phone": $("#phone").val()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: console.log("it did not work"),
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: .toString() is actually a JavaScript function.

Comment: On a side note, if I have the following in my controller,

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.phone))
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Phone is required", Status = "error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

how can i use this to show an alert in the view?

Comment: @user2094139, this is really a separate question, but here you are :).  Because you are actually return Json, you are returning a 200 call, meaning that you will hit the success callback.  As such, just do the following in your success callback.  success: function (data) { alert(data.Message); }

Comment: @David L Thank you so much, I thought it was that actually.. but for some reason it wasnt working earlier. THanks for clarifying it for me though.